# Django form floatfield separator

Tags: django

I have a form floatfield. What is the best way to change the default separator from '.' to ','?
I tried to set the DECIMAL_SEPARATOR in the settings to ',' but this doesn't help.
Is there a way to configure this or do I have to overwrite the clean method of the floatfield?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`FloatField` does not support i18n; you'll have to write your own.

Answer (score -1):

Since django 1.2, `FloatField` has a `localize` member. You can set it to True. The coma separator will be accepted if you local is french for example.

for example:

```
class MyForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(MyForm).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
         self.fields['my_float'].localize = True
```

or

```
 MyForm(Form):
     my_float = forms.FloatField(localize=True)
```